# About conditional expectations

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

This is a question I have after reading this (page 41) https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01816069/document

I wonder how is it possible to condition the expectation on the right-hand side without having the left-hand side also conditioned on $\mathcal F_t$ and $\tilde \theta \in \Theta^{opt}_t$. Is there any property on conditional expectations that I'm probably missing? It's like having two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\leq Y$ and then writing $X \leq \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$ for some sigma algebra $\mathcal G$. Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: I didn't read the original source. But you can check whether $R_{t}^{\mathrm{TS}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable, if so, $\mathbb{E}[R_{t}^{\mathrm{TS}}|\mathcal{F}_{t},\tilde{\theta}\in\Theta_{t}^{\mathrm{opt}}]=\mathbb{E}[R_{t}^{\mathrm{TS}}|\mathcal{F}_{t}]=R_{t}^{\mathrm{TS}}$, this explains the LHS.

Comment: @Q9y5: That makes perfect sense. By the way, do you have any idea how the conditional expectation in both sigma algebra and event work? My guess is that the probability measure for defining the conditional expectation is the one conditioned on $\tilde\theta \in \Theta^{opt}_t$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Conditional on an event is nothing but $\mathbb{E}[\cdot|E]=\mathbb{E}[\cdot|1_{E}=1]$, and $\mathbb{E}[\cdot|1_{E}]=\mathbb{E}[\cdot|\sigma(1_{E})]$. So you first conditional on the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ and $\sigma(1{\{\tilde{\theta}\in\Theta_{t}^{\mathrm{opt}}\}})$,(which would be a function of $1{\{\tilde{\theta}\in\Theta_{t}^{\mathrm{opt}}\}}$) then take $1{\{\tilde{\theta}\in\Theta_{t}^{\mathrm{opt}}\}}=1$.